# asp.net C# GridView run twice. Duplicate results

Tags: asp.net

I tried to set sums on footer in gridview. I had succeded this but if I add a small piece of code it duplicates the results. For exapmple instead of 2 it appears 4. It seems that run twice.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int[] sum_nmb = new int[30] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int count_col = 0;
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
        }
        date_textbox.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label10.Text = date_textbox.Text;
        Label13.Text = date_textbox.Text;
    }

     protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType== DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            count_col = 0;
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                try
                {
                    sum_nmb[count_col] = sum_nmb[count_col] + Int32.Parse(e.Row.Cells[count_col].Text);
                }
                catch
                {
                    sum_nmb[count_col] = sum_nmb[count_col] + 0;
                }
                count_col = count_col + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (sum_nmb[i] != 0)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Text = sum_nmb[i].ToString();
                }
                else if (sum_nmb[i]==0 && i > 0)//if I remove this "else if" block it works like a charm
                {//
                    GridView1.Columns[i].Visible = false;//
                }//

            }
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Σύνολο:";
            e.Row.Cells[27].Text = " ";
        }
    }
```

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" AllowSorting="True" ShowFooter="True" CssClass="auto-style8" GridLines="Vertical" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Strikeout="False" OnRowDataBound="gridview1_RowDataBound">
```

I had read that maybe is a bug but I couldn't figure it out.
Thnx in advance

Comment: Which small piece of code?

Comment: else if (sum_nmb[i]==0 && i > 0)
                {
                    GridView1.Columns[i].Visible = false;
                }

Comment: I tried to add different code solutions. But when i added extra code in gridview1_RowDataBound it happens the same. It run twice.